# Deleting SQL Server 2014 Instance

Tags: sql-server

I am struggling to find an answer as the word "Instance" has been interpreted as the entire SQL Server 2014 *Program* on the web.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/ckW7A]

At the moment, there are two instances (we'll call them red and blue instances respectively). I want to delete the blue instance *but* retain the red instance and SQL Server 2014 itself.

Looking under Add/Remove Programs, SQL Server 2014 has only the option of "Uninstall" but "Modify" has been disabled.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: An SQL Server instance is a complete SQL server and you can install many instances on a machine but you can have only 1 default instance. An SQL Server instance has its own copy of the server files, databases and security credentials. ... Each instance manages several system databases and one or more user

Answer (score 0):

Choose remove/uninstall, this will launch SQL setup and you can choose the instance to remove features from, and then the features themselves. If in doubt, install a couple of local instances of developer edition & practice on those.
NB: You'll only be able to pick instances matching the version and architecture (x86/x64) of the uninstaller you clicked on uninstall/remove for.

[image: Add/Remove]

[image: Choose instance]

[image: Choose features]